# Surface area (Hyperboloid and Ellipsoid)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> (Show work please) Calculate the surface area of the hyperboloid
>    $8x^2 + 12y^2 - 16z^2 = 1$ inside of the ellipsoid
>    $2x^2 + 3y^2 + 4z^2 = 1$.

I started doing $2x^2 + 3y^2 = 1 - 4z^2 \implies 8x^2 + 12x^2 = 4 - 16z^2$ putting this in the equation of the hyperboloid $4 - 16z^2 - 16z^2 = 1 \implies z = \pm \sqrt{3/32}$. Does this mean that the required area of the hyperboloid is between those planes? If yes, how do I calculate this area?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your post to show your work and thoughts on the problem thus far. Let us know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

A parametrization for the hyperboloid is
$$\left(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)\right)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\mathrm{ch} u\cos v,\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\mathrm{ch} u\sin v,\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{sh}u\right)\quad\quad(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}\times(0,2\pi).$$
Indeed, the map $X:(u,v)\mapsto\left(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)\right)$ is a diffeomorphism form $\mathbb{R}\times(0,2\pi)$ to its image (the hyperboloid minus the curve parametrized by $u=0$) with $8x^2+12y^2-16z^2=1$.

The tangent space at a point $\left(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)\right)$ is spanned by the two tangent vectors

$$\begin{cases}
X_u\equiv X_u(u,v)\equiv\frac{\partial X}{\partial u}(u,v)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\mathrm{sh} u\cos v,\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\mathrm{sh} u\sin v,\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{ch}u\right) \\
X_v\equiv X_u(u,v)\equiv\frac{\partial X}{\partial u}(u,v)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\mathrm{sh} u\sin v,\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\mathrm{sh} u\cos v,0\right)
\end{cases}.$$
If we let $Y(v):=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\cos v,\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\sin v,0\right)$, $Y'(v):=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\sin v,\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\cos v,0\right)$ and $N:=\left(0,0,\frac{1}{4}\right)$ (observe that $Y(v)$ and $N$ are orthogonal, as are $Y'(v)$ and $N$), then we can write
$$\begin{cases}
X_u=\mathrm{sh}u Y(v)+\mathrm{ch}u N \\
X_v=\mathrm{ch}u Y'(v)
\end{cases}.$$

Now the area. Let $E:=|X_u|^2$, $F:=X_u\cdot X_v$ and $G:=|X_v|^2$, where $\cdot$ is the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $|.|$ the corresponding norm. We have :
$$\begin{align}
E=|X_u|^2 & =\mathrm{sh}^2u|Y(v)|^2+\mathrm{ch}^2u|N|^2 \\
& =\mathrm{sh}^2u\left(\frac{\cos^2 v}{8}+\frac{\sin^2 v}{12}\right)+\frac{\mathrm{ch}^2u}{16} \\
& =\frac{\mathrm{sh}^2u}{12}\left(\frac{\cos^2 v}{2}+1\right)+\frac{\mathrm{ch}^2u}{16} \\
& =\frac{\mathrm{sh}^2u}{48}\left(\cos2v+5\right)+\frac{\mathrm{ch}^2u}{16},
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
F=X_u\cdot X_v & =\mathrm{sh}u\mathrm{ch}uY(v)\cdot Y'(v) \\
& = \mathrm{sh}u\mathrm{ch}u\sin v\cos v\left(-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{12}\right) \\
& =-\frac{1}{24}\mathrm{sh}u\mathrm{ch}u\sin v\cos v,
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
G=|X_v|^2 & =\mathrm{ch}^2u|Y'(v)|^2 \\
& =\mathrm{ch}^2u\left(\frac{\sin^2 v}{8}+\frac{\cos^2 v}{12}\right) \\
& =\frac{\mathrm{ch}^2u}{12}\left(\frac{\sin^2 v}{2}+1\right) \\
& =\frac{\mathrm{ch}^2u}{48}\left(5-\cos2v\right).
\end{align}$$
The formula for the area $\mathcal{A}$ is therefore
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{A} & :=\int\int\sqrt{EG-F^2}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v \\
& =\int\int\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{sh}^2u\mathrm{ch}^2u}{2304}\left(25-\cos^22v\right)+\frac{\mathrm{ch}^4u}{768}\left(5-2\cos2v\right)-\frac{\mathrm{sh}^2u\mathrm{ch}^2u\sin^2v\cos^2v}{576}}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v \\
& =\int\int\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{sh}^2u\mathrm{ch}^2u}{2304}\left(25-\cos^22v-2 \sin^22v\right)+\frac{\mathrm{ch}^4u}{768}\left(5-2\cos2v\right)}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v \\
& =\frac{1}{16\sqrt{3}}\int\int\sqrt{\frac{\mathrm{sh}^2u\mathrm{ch}^2u}{3}\left(24- \sin^22v\right)+\mathrm{ch}^4u\left(5-2\cos2v\right)}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align}$$
where the integral is computed on the domains $|u|<\mathrm{argsh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$ and $0<v<2\pi$.

It will be difficult to get the exact formula for the area here (as you can see by integrating with respect to one variable with an integral calculator). However, we can bound the value of $\mathcal{A}$ by taking the maximum inside the square root (as $u$ and $cos$, $sin$ are bounded) ; we get the following majoration :
$$\mathcal{A}\leq\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{267+\frac{113}{2}\sqrt{15}}\simeq12.2409.$$

Comment: @danilocn94 Has my answer been useful ?

Comment: I didn't understand very well what you have done. Could you explain why I can't simply calculate the surface area of  the hyperboloid between the planes that I found ? And could you explain a little better what you have done, please ?

Comment: @danilocn94 Well, we need to define a parametrization $X(u,v)$ of the surface to get the vectors $X_u$ and $X_v$ as defined above ; then, the surface area is given by the integral of $|X_u\wedge X_v|$. It is often useful in differential geometry to introduce the quantities E,F and G defined above ; then, if $\theta$ is the angle between $X_u$ and $X_v$ in a tangent sapce, we have $|X_u\wedge X_v|^2=|X_u|^2|X_v|^2\sin^2\theta=|X_u|^2|X_v|^2(1-\cos^2\theta)=|X_u|^2|X_v|^2-|X_u\cdot X_v|^2=EG-F^2$, and thus the area is the integral of $\sqrt{EG-F^2}$.

Comment: @danilocn94 You can directly  compute the wedge product if you want and forget the coefficients E,F and G, it must not change the result. As for the integral bounds, I've of course used ones you found (for $z$). The resulting integral is really tricky, and I've just given an upper bound to it.